# Can I create a AWS network load balancer manually for a Kubernetes service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, kubernetes-service

When creating a Kubernetes service of type `LoadBalancer` on an EKS cluster, a load balancer is automatically provisioned by the AWS Load Balancer Controller.

For specific reasons, I'd like to have more control over the configuration of the load balancer than what is provided by the [AWS Load Balancer service annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/).

**Question: I'd like to know if it's possible to create the load balancer before the Kubernetes service (say in Terraform), and configure the Kubernetes service to use the load balancer (for example by providing the AWS Load Balancer Controller with the load balancer name).**

Some research: I found the service annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name`, but it seems to be used to create a load balancer with the specified name, rather than find and use an existing load balancer with the specified name.

Comment: Take a look on this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

Comment: The service of the type load balancer will expose the deployment you are running. On AWS it's an ELB or NLB. You can also opt to use an ingress if you bring your own lb devices. For instance an haproxy. But it won't have the benefit of having a selector that will link the service to the deployment, you will have to do the configuring of the backend manually.